# Style on an Included Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, combobox, datatrigger

I have a usercontrol (customized ComboBox) which I am including in another usercontrol. I want to set a style on that Customized ComboBox UserControl based on the data in the main usercontrol in which I am including my ComboBox Usercontrol.

Here is my Code

```
<MultiSelectComboBox:MultiUnitSelectControl x:Name="MultiUnitCombo" Grid.Row="0" Width="90" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding LstUnit}" Margin="0,10,0,2" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <MultiSelectComboBox:MultiUnitSelectControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count,ElementName=UnitCombo}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MultiSelectComboBox:MultiUnitSelectControl.Style>
</MultiSelectComboBox:MultiUnitSelectControl>
```

This is my customized usercontrol. Now what I want is I want to Collapse it when the Items Count is equal to 1. UnitCombo is a combobox in my main UserControl based on its itemsCount I want to set the Visibility on the Included UserControl.

however when I apply this Style to the ComboBox in the Main UserControl It works

```
<ComboBox.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger
                                                        Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, ElementName=UnitCombo}"
                                                        Value="1">
                                                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />

                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ComboBox.Style>
```

But applying the same style on the Included UserControl doesnt show up anything.It kind of Hangs the whole view and shows nothing as if the controls are Hidden or something.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are filling your `UnitCombo` by setting its `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection`, then you will need to bind to `ItemsSource.Count` instead of    `Items.Count`.

```
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ItemsSource.Count,ElementName=UnitCombo}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
```

It will work.